# How do you read boolean values from cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Here's my current cookie function so far:

```
function getCookie(name, type) {
                var nameEQ = name + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                    x = c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
                    if (type=="Bool") {
                         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return x;
                    } else {
                         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return parseInt(x);
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
```

However, the boolean values don't return correctly. The integer values do, though. If someone could help that would be awesome, I've been searching for 30 minutes, and still haven't found the answer.

Comment: How does `name` look like? Maybe you want `Boolean(x)`

Comment: @elclanrs, Does boolean(x) return a boolean from a string, like parseBoolean() would do, but different?

Comment: I think cookies are only strings. With what string you represent true and false is up to you. And parse them accordingly. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Boolean(x) will NOT correctly convert your String to true or false. It considers every non-empty (`""`) String to be true. Instead compare your String to `"true"` or whatever other value you want to signal a positive boolean output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your conditional, it looks like you just `return x` (a String) instead of first converting it to a boolean value. I would suggest:

```
if (type=="Bool") {
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return (x == "true");
} else {
    ...
}
```

You could vary this implementation- I have just chosen to consider `"true"` the only valid String for boolean true; all others are considered false (regardless of whether they actually match the String `"false"`).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do it this way, but there are certainly other right answers. I feel it's more readable, but some would def disagree.

```
for(...){
    ... other ...
    var isMatch = !!~c.indexOf(name);
    if (!isMatch) return;

    return (type=="Bool") ? x == 'true' : parseInt(x);
}
```

Comment: Were you meaning to add the bitwise NOT `~` on line 3? I agree that this is more concise, however the question was only concerning incorrect boolean returns so I didn't refactor it entirely. Note that `/^true$/g.test(x)` appears [~98%](http://jsperf.com/string-true) slower than `x == "true"`, if you don't mind case-sensitive cookie matching.

Comment: yes, about the bitwise op -- shorter way do the `indexOf()` thing. It's working with type coercion... basically the only result that evaluates as false-y is -1. And totally wasn't ripping on your "non-refactor" answer. I like concise, but it comes with a price(98/100, i hear). it makes sense, though. I appreciate you passing that on!

Comment: My bad; cool trick. I do enjoy bit-twiddling/type coercion shortcuts, they're one of my favorite parts about Javascript. And I wasn't intending to bash on your answer, either- for case-insensitive comparisons I noticed it was actually faster than `x.toLowerCase() == "true"`. Just wanted to make others aware of the potential costs, before implementing one or the other :)

Comment: For anyone curious- see the description [here](http://jsperf.com/string-true/2) for case-insensitive comparison benchmarks.